# Having Difficulty Changing IMG Src inside a UL on click with already existing on click functionality

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

You can see a sample here:
https://blennd.com/

Scroll down to "What we do".

On Blendd there are 4 svg images, 1 that is active by default. When you click the next image, a new set of text appears beneath the container that holds all of the images.

This is the exact function I am trying to implement. I went to codepen again and experimented. This is what I came up with:

https://codepen.io/Lancewalker/pen/zepjXr

The step that is holding me back is changing the img src when clicking each img. The entire functionality that I want is there other than that.

If there is another way that's even better to do this other than having an img src I am open to that as well.

```js
 // tabbed content
    // http://www.entheosweb.com/tutorials/css/tabs.asp
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();

  /* if in tab mode */
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
  
      $(".tab_content").hide();
      var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();  
  
      $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");

   $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
   $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='"+activeTab+"']").addClass("d_active");
   
    });
 /* if in drawer mode */
 $(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {
      
      $(".tab_content").hide();
      var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeIn();
   
   $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
      $(this).addClass("d_active");
   
   $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
   $("ul.tabs li[rel^='"+d_activeTab+"']").addClass("active");
    });
 
 
 /* Extra class "tab_last" 
    to add border to right side
    of last tab */
 $('ul.tabs li').last().addClass("tab_last");
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
ul.tabs {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 height: 232px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
 width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul.tabs img{
width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

ul.tabs li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 0px 0px;
  margin: 0 -20px;
 height: 232px;
 line-height: 31px;

 color: #ccc;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}


ul.tabs li.active {
 color: #333;
 display: block;
}

.tab_container {
  padding-top: 75px;
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab_content {
 padding: 20px;
 display: none;
}

.tab_drawer_heading { display: none; }

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .tabs {
  display: none;
 }
 .tab_drawer_heading {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
 }
 .d_active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
 }
}

#img2 {
  margin-top: 90px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active" rel="tab1"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/qDiv1eb.png"></li>
  <li rel="tab2" id="img2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/Yu991zv.png"></li>
  <li rel="tab3"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/JYrxfHv.png"></li>
  <li rel="tab4" id="img2"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/1ub27In.png"></li>
  <li rel="tab5"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/7Bi6rVL.png"></li>

</ul>

<div class="tab_container">
  <h3 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab 1</h3>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
  <h2>Tab 1 content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac metus augue.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab1 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab 2</h3>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
  <h2>Tab 2 content</h2>
    <p>Nunc dui velit, scelerisque eu placerat volutpat, dapibus eu nisi. Vivamus eleifend vestibulum odio non vulputate.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab2 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab3">Tab 3</h3>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
  <h2>Tab 3 content</h2>
    <p>Nulla eleifend felis vitae velit tristique imperdiet. Etiam nec imperdiet elit. Pellentesque sem lorem, scelerisque sed facilisis sed, vestibulum sit amet eros.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab3 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab4">Tab 4</h3>
  <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
  <h2>Tab 4 content</h2>
    <p>Integer ultrices lacus sit amet lorem viverra consequat. Vivamus lacinia interdum sapien non faucibus. Maecenas bibendum, lectus at ultrices viverra, elit magna egestas magna, a adipiscing mauris justo nec eros.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab4 --> 
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab5">Tab 5</h3>
  <div id="tab5" class="tab_content">
  <h2>Tab 5 content</h2>
    <p>Integer ultrices lacus sit amet lorem viverra consequat. Vivamus lacinia interdum sapien non faucibus. Maecenas bibendum, lectus at ultrices viverra, elit magna egestas magna, a adipiscing mauris justo nec eros.</p>
  </div>
    <!-- #tab5 --> 
</div>
<!-- .tab_container -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by having two `<img>` in the tab and a few CSS codes.

> Note: Active and Inactive images are different here, you can change accordingly.

This is the added CSS.

```
ul.tabs li.active > img.img-inactive {
    display: none;
}
ul.tabs li.active > img.img-active {
    display: block;
}
ul.tabs li > img.img-active {
    display: none;
}
```

```js
// tabbed content
    // http://www.entheosweb.com/tutorials/css/tabs.asp
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();

  /* if in tab mode */
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
  
      $(".tab_content").hide();
      var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();  
  
      $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");

   $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
   $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='"+activeTab+"']").addClass("d_active");
   
    });
 /* if in drawer mode */
 $(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {
      
      $(".tab_content").hide();
      var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeIn();
   
   $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
      $(this).addClass("d_active");
   
   $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
   $("ul.tabs li[rel^='"+d_activeTab+"']").addClass("active");
    });
 
 
 /* Extra class "tab_last" 
    to add border to right side
    of last tab */
 $('ul.tabs li').last().addClass("tab_last");
```

```css
/*************New CSS*/
ul.tabs li.active > img.img-inactive {
    display: none;
}
ul.tabs li.active > img.img-active {
    display: block;
}
ul.tabs li > img.img-active {
    display: none;
}
/**********New CSS*/
body {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
ul.tabs {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 height: 232px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
 width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul.tabs img{
width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

ul.tabs li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 0px 0px;
  margin: 0 -20px;
 height: 232px;
 line-height: 31px;

 color: #ccc;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}


ul.tabs li.active {
 color: #333;
 display: block;
}

.tab_container {
  padding-top: 75px;
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab_content {
 padding: 20px;
 display: none;
}

.tab_drawer_heading { display: none; }

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .tabs {
  display: none;
 }
 .tab_drawer_heading {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
 }
 .d_active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active" rel="tab1">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qDiv1eb.png" class="img-active">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Yu991zv.png" class="img-inactive">
   </li>
  <li rel="tab2" id="img2">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qDiv1eb.png" class="img-active">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Yu991zv.png" class="img-inactive">
    </li>

</ul>
<div class="tab_container">
  <h3 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab 1</h3>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 1 content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac metus augue.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab1 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab 2</h3>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 2 content</h2>
    <p>Nunc dui velit, scelerisque eu placerat volutpat, dapibus eu nisi. Vivamus eleifend vestibulum odio non vulputate.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly, thank you so much!

```js
// tabbed content
    // http://www.entheosweb.com/tutorials/css/tabs.asp
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    $(".tab_content:first").show();

  /* if in tab mode */
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
  
      $(".tab_content").hide();
      var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();  
  
      $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");

   $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
   $(".tab_drawer_heading[rel^='"+activeTab+"']").addClass("d_active");
   
    });
 /* if in drawer mode */
 $(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {
      
      $(".tab_content").hide();
      var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeIn();
   
   $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
      $(this).addClass("d_active");
   
   $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
   $("ul.tabs li[rel^='"+d_activeTab+"']").addClass("active");
    });
 
 
 /* Extra class "tab_last" 
    to add border to right side
    of last tab */
 $('ul.tabs li').last().addClass("tab_last");
```

```css
/*************New CSS*/
ul.tabs li.active > img.img-inactive {
    display: none;
}
ul.tabs li.active > img.img-active {
    display: block;
}
ul.tabs li > img.img-active {
    display: none;
}
/**********New CSS*/
body {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
ul.tabs {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: left;
 list-style: none;
 height: 232px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
 width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

ul.tabs img{
width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

ul.tabs li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 0px 0px;
  margin: 0 -20px;
 height: 232px;
 line-height: 31px;

 color: #ccc;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}


ul.tabs li.active {
 color: #333;
 display: block;
}

.tab_container {
  padding-top: 75px;
 clear: both;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab_content {
 padding: 20px;
 display: none;
}

.tab_drawer_heading { display: none; }

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .tabs {
  display: none;
 }
 .tab_drawer_heading {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  border-top: 1px solid #333;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
 }
 .d_active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active" rel="tab1">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qDiv1eb.png" class="img-active">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Yu991zv.png" class="img-inactive">
   </li>
  <li rel="tab2" id="img2">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/qDiv1eb.png" class="img-active">
   <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Yu991zv.png" class="img-inactive">
    </li>

</ul>
<div class="tab_container">
  <h3 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab 1</h3>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 1 content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac metus augue.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab1 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab 2</h3>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
    <h2>Tab 2 content</h2>
    <p>Nunc dui velit, scelerisque eu placerat volutpat, dapibus eu nisi. Vivamus eleifend vestibulum odio non vulputate.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```